# How to remove parent and display only the child in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list coming from an external data. 
All h1 elements are displayed inside a p element like this:

```
<p><h1>Heading</h1></p>
```

I would like to remove the p element and display only h3:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

Using the script below I delete both:

```
$('h1').parents('p').remove();
```

How can I reach my goal?

Comment: [`.unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

Comment: not a valid html, you can't use `h1` as child of `p`

Comment: As @PranavCBalan has said most browsers well see this as invalid and well take it out of the `<p>` automatically. It would be better if you could change it before adding it to the page. Other wise you have bunch of empty `<p>` tags on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.unwrap`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) function to remove parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('h1').unwrap();
  }, 1000);
})
```

```css
div {
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: red;
}
h1 {
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
```

---

Also you have invalid HTML, because `h1` can't be inside `p` ([HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element))

Answer (score 0):

How about Unwrap ? ?

```
<div class="parent">
<p class="child">
</p>
</div>
```

after using - `$(".child").unwrap()` - it will be;

```
<p class="child">
</p>
```